# How to invoke Sling Servlet that uses "resourceType" instead of "paths" in @SlingServlet annotation

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

How do I invoke a Sling Servlet that uses the "resourceType" property inside @SlingServlet?  When I use"paths" I just call it with an ajax call but I am not sure what to do if I change my servlet to use "resourceType" instead of "paths".  (I am making the change for learning purposes)

I am still learning CQ5, Sling, etc.

My servlet follows.

```
package com.mypackage.weather;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.*;
import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@SlingServlet(
        name="Weatherservlet",
        //paths="/bin/Weather",
        resourceType="OpenWeather/components/page/contentPage",
        methods="GET",
        metatype=true)
@Properties({
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name="WeatherServlet", description="Get JSON String weather info", value="mitch weather"),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "apikey", label = "The api key", value = "d8e39388b0bc54a62ffc6b385639b3dc") // register the api key in the OSGi console
})

/**
 * Handles requests for getting weather information from OpenWeatherMap.org.  returns the information as a JSon string.
 */
public class WeatherServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    private static final String SERVER = "localhost:4502";
    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "/content/OpenWeather";
    private String apikey = "";
    private String location = "";
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeatherServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Reconfigured Weather Servlet");
        getWeather(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * Gets current weather information from OpenWeatherMap.org API
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void getWeather(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response)   {
        logger.info("api key: " + apikey);
        location = request.getParameter("city");
        logger.info("city sent: " + location);
        String urlString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + "&units=imperial&APPID=" + apikey;
        logger.info("urlString: " + urlString);
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        int responseCode = -9;
        String result = "";
        logger.info("Before call to Open Weather");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            logger.info("url: " + url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            logger.info("Connection: " + connection);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            logger.info("After calling Open Weather");
            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            logger.info("reader: " + reader);
            result = reader.readLine();
            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            logger.info("Elapsed Time is... " + elapsedTime);
            logger.info("result: " + result);
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            writer.write(result);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.info("MalformedURL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info("IOException!!!!!!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("Cause: " + e.getCause());
        }
    }


    protected void activate(ComponentContext context)
    {
        apikey = PropertiesUtil.toString(context.getProperties().get("apikey"), "d8e39388b0bc54a62ffc6b385639b3dc"); // Get the api key from the OSGi console
        System.out.println("weather servlet activated");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of making ajax call to the path in the servlet, you make an ajax call to the component. In case you want the servlet to work with **resourceType** the servlet should have an additional configuration for extensions property (**sling.servlet.extensions**).This configuration let's you run a servlet in context of a resource(of a particular resourceType) instead of a global one.

Let me explain with an example. Consider a page content/home.html with a **foo** component (**resourceType="/apps/someproject/components/foo**) at path **/par/foo** . Normally on a page the component will be requested with .html selector and the resource will be rendered by the default script (**foo.jsp**). Let's add a servlet with the following annotation

`@SlingServlet(
        name="Weatherservlet",
        extensions = "pdf",
        resourceType="someproject/components/foo",
        methods="GET",
        metatype=true)` which will give pdf representation of the resource.

A GET request to `/content/home/jcr:content/par/foo.pdf` will be handled by the servlet instead of **foo.jsp**.

`request.getResource()` inside the servlet's `doGet` will return the component resource.

path configuration will override the resourceType configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your answer along with a colleague's is helping me to more fully understand how to do Sling servlets with resourceType.

Comment: Note that absolute resource types like /apps/someproject/components/foo are not recommended, you should use someproject/components/foo in this case. /apps is a prefix defined by the Sling resolver configuration, which could change in the future.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz , thanks for pointing it. Changed the code

Comment: Can any one of you answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076684/cq5-accessing-osgi-servlet-through-url

Comment: Excellent and clear answer here.  Well done, Sharath.