# cq5 accessing osgi servlet through Url

Tags: aem, sling

I am trying to access following sling servlet using `http://localhost:4502/sling/test-services/planet.html`

But, it is giving 404 error, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
@Component
@Service(value=javax.servlet.Servlet.class)
@Properties({
    @Property(name="service.description", value="HTML renderer for Planet resources"),
    @Property(name="service.vendor", value="The Apache Software Foundation"),
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value="sling/test-services/planet"),
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.extensions", value="html"),
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.methods", value="GET")
})
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PlanetResourceRenderingServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        final ValueMap properties = request.getResource().adaptTo(ValueMap.class);

        // TODO should escape output - good enough for our tests 
        final PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println(String.format("<html><head><title>Planet at %s</title></head><body>", request.getResource().getPath()));
        pw.println(String.format("<p>Name: %s</p>", properties.get("name")));
        pw.println(String.format("<p>Distance: %s</p>", properties.get("distance")));
        pw.println("</body></html>");
        pw.flush();
    }

}
```

Is it possible, I could access the servlet service without ".html" extension, if I remove extension property?

I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

When you want to access a servlet through an URL you need to set the `sling.servlet.paths` instead of the `sling.servlet.resourceTypes`. A similar issue has been [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149751/unable-to-deploy-slingservlet-in-cq/23150133#23150133)

If you are setting the `sling.servlet.resourceTypes` property, then you need to access a resource whose `sling:resourceType` is `sling/test-services/planet`.

Your annotations should be

```
@Component
@Service(value=javax.servlet.Servlet.class)
@Properties({
    @Property(name="service.description", value="HTML renderer for Planet resources"),
    @Property(name="service.vendor", value="The Apache Software Foundation"),
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.paths", value="/sling/test-services/planet"),
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.extensions", value="html"),
    @Property(name="sling.servlet.methods", value="GET")
})
```

Or this can be further simplified using the `@SlingServlet` annotation as shown below

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/sling/test-services/planet", methods="GET", extensions="html")
```

Make sure that you allow the following path is allowed in `Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler` configuration available in OSGi console.

Comment: I will try with paths. I see lot of servlets wit path "/bin" , should I need to have the as "/bin/sling/test-services/planet" or "sling/test-services/planet" would work ?

Comment: `/bin` is allowed in the Script Resolver configuration by default. Hence using `/bin/sling/test-services/planet` wouldn't require any change in the configuration. But if you use `/sling/test-services/planet`, you may need to allow `/sling/` in the Script Resolver explicitly.

Comment: As usual, let me remind people that registering Sling servlets by path is not recommended if you can avoid it, see the "sling.servlets.path" section at https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html